# Complex query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my Problem: 
I have a table that holds a few columns

```
(Id, email, last_visit_date, picture)
```

The picture column can has 3 options:

- user with no picture -> "noPic"
- user with private picture -> "privatePic"
- user with picture -> "pic2" ("pic" & userID)

I need a query (for MySQL) that will return all rows in the order:

1. All the users with pictures order by last_visit_date
2. All the users with private pictures order by last_visit_date
3. All the users without pictures order by last_visit_date

I could not figure that out

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY picture LIKE 'pic%' DESC, picture = "noPic" DESC, last_visit_date
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql will implicitly convert bool values to integers (1 and 0 respectively). you can thus sort by comparing the picture value:

```
ORDER BY picture = 'privatePic' ASC, picture = 'noPic' ASC, last_visit_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a case/when construct in your order by clause... In this case, I set values to 1, 2 or 3, THEN order by the last visit date...

```
select
      YT.*
   from
      YourTable YT
   order by
      case when YT.Picture = "noPic" then 1
           when YT.Picture = "PrivatePic" then 2
           else 3 
      end,
      YT.Last_Visit_Date desc
```